# What's the accurate meaning of $\partial f\over {\partial\mathbf{y}}$?

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to \mathbb{R}^m,\ \mathbf{t}=[x_1,\cdots,x_m,y_1,\cdots,y_n]\to [f_1(\mathbf{t}),\cdots,f_m(\mathbf{t})]$ be a differentiable function. Here $[a_1,\cdots,a_m]$ means a column vector with a height of $m.$ I think that the symbol $\partial f\over {\partial \mathbf{y}}$ represents the matrix
\begin{equation*}     \left(                \begin{array}{cccc}   \displaystyle{{\partial f_1}\over {\partial y_1}}&\displaystyle{{\partial f_1}\over {\partial y_2}}&\cdots&\displaystyle{{\partial f_1}\over {\partial y_n}}\\    \displaystyle{{\partial f_2}\over {\partial y_1}}&\displaystyle{{\partial f_2}\over {\partial y_2}}&\cdots&\displaystyle{{\partial f_2}\over {\partial y_n}}\\ 
  \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
 \displaystyle {{\partial f_m}\over {\partial y_1}}&\displaystyle{{\partial f_m}\over {\partial y_2}}&\cdots&\displaystyle{{\partial f_m}\over {\partial y_n}}
\end{array}
\right) ,     \end{equation*}
so when $m=1,$ we have ${\partial f\over {\partial \mathbf{y}}}=({\partial f\over {\partial y_1}},\cdots,{\partial f\over {\partial y_n}}).$ Thus $\partial f\over{\partial\mathbf{y}}$ is a row vector.

But in mechanics the following equation can be seen everywhere:
$$m{d\mathbf{v}\over{dt}}=-{\partial U\over \partial{\mathbf{r}}}. $$
But if we view radius vector $\mathbf{r}$ as a column vector, then $\displaystyle{d\mathbf{v}\over{dt}}$ is a column vector, so it seems that 
$$ {\partial U\over \partial{\mathbf{r}}}=[{\partial U\over {\partial x}},{\partial U\over {\partial y}},{\partial U\over {\partial z}}],$$
which contradicts my definition.

**Question:** Should the equation be rewritten as 
$$m{d\mathbf{v}\over{dt}}=-\Big({\partial U\over \partial{\mathbf{r}}}\Big)^T ?$$

Comment: Nothing stops you from writing the acceleration vector as a column vector in your equation which makes it all correct, there are actually two layouts for the gradient https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write the equation you are considering is $m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} = -\nabla U$, where $\nabla U$ is the gradient, which spits out a vector.  As you observe, the Jacobian $\frac{d U}{d\mathbf{x}}$ is not the same as the gradient $\nabla U$ (strictly speaking, the entries are the same, but the Jacobian has a preferred matrix dimension, thus we can use Jacobian notation, but it's a bit of an abuse of notation).

Whether you choose to write $\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}$ and $\nabla U$ as row or column vectors in this equation is really your personal preference.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force

Comment: Ummm, but when the potential energy is determined by more than one objects, we have $U=U(\mathbf{r_1},\cdots,\mathbf{r_s}),$ and it seems that many physicists use the symbol ${\partial U\over{\partial \mathbf{r_i}}}$ to represent a column vector...

Comment: physicists like to abuse all kinds of symbols. What they mean is gradient of a real valued function.  Note that if each $\mathbf{r_i}$ is the distance from your particle to some fixed object of a given mass, then it is in fact just a function of the position of your particle (i.e. the coordinate $\mathbf{x}$). In general, if multiple particles are moving then you have a bigger configuration space, but the $\mathbf{r_i}$ are still all functions of the position coordinates, so really $U = U(\mathbf{r}_1, \ldots \mathbf{r}_s) = U(\mathbf{r}_1(\mathbf{x}), \ldots \mathbf{r}_s(\mathbf{x}))$.

Comment: $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \vec{x}}$ is a gradient though, or it's transpose depending on your layout choice, it satisfies all the conditions of being the vector of partial derivatives of the scalar function. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: Yes, the entries are the same. But the Jacobian has a fixed choice of matrix dimensions, which is the source of OP's confusion. The definition as a gradient and not a Jacobian is the reason that taking transpose doesn't matter.